# Likelihood for a test data (sequence of characters) given two unigram models

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, natural-language, language-models, corpus-linguistics

I would like to find the *likelihood* of a sequence of characters (the test data), given two unigram models.

The sequence (test data) is:

```
A B C B B
```

The models are:

```
       Model 1       Model 2
P(A)     0.3           0.4  
P(B)     0.4           0.5  
P(C)     0.3           0.1
```

Basically, I would like to know the likelihood, and if I can make a prediction as to which model the sequence belong and the underlying assumptions. I understand that given any unigram language model, the likelihood (or probability) of any sequence of characters is p(sequence of characters|Model).

What I have done so far was to find the MLE for each character:

P(A) = $\frac{1}{5}$ ; P(B) = $\frac{2}{5}$ ; P(C) = $\frac{1}{5}$

I don't know how to compute p(sequence of characters|Model). Should I multiply these to find the likelihood and establish which model it came from? How to handle the model probabilities given?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that to compute **p(sequence of characters|Model)** you just have to multiply the probabilities of each character in the model by the number of times it appear in the test sequence. E.g. model 1, it is simply: $0.3 * 0.4 * 0.3 * 0.4 * 0.4$